# How to get the exact BBox for svg <tspan>

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to figure out why `getBBox()` for `tspan` element of a svg does not return the dimension.

To demonstrate this with an example, if I run BBox on both `tsp1` and `rect1`, it returns the correct dimension for `rect1` but not for `tsp1`

```js
var tsp = document.getElementById('tsp1');
var tspBBox = tsp.getBBox();
var rect = document.getElementById('rect1');
var rectBBox = rect.getBBox();
console.log(tspBBox);
console.log(rectBBox);
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">

    <text class="t1" id="t1" font-size="20" font-family="PT Mono" text-decoration="underline">
        <tspan class="tsp1" id="tsp1" x="10.23" y="135.05">Abc ef ghi</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect class="rect1" id="rect1" x="9.23" y="112.73368530273439" height="31.546314697265625" width="1" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

[image: S1]

I was expecting `BBox` to return the exact `x` and `y` for `tsp1` but it does not.
I  don't know why. I need to pass on the exact values to the succeeding class dynamically.

How can javascript return the exact dimension for the `tspan` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a [number of methods](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#InterfaceSVGTextContentElement) for measuring text, and they are a bit more complex than defining a simple box. This is because with the [`dx`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextElementDXAttribute), [`dy`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextElementDYAttribute) and [`rotate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextElementRotateAttribute) attributes, each [addressable character](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TermAddressableCharacter) can be be positioned individually - moved and rotated in every direction. Therefore, it makes more sense to answer the question where a single character is positioned, and where, after completing one sequence, the next character would be positioned.

In your case none of the above attributes are set ( on the `<tspan>` or `<text>` element). In this case is is possible to retrieve the start position of the `<tspan>` with [`.getStartPositionOfChar(0)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getStartPositionOfChar) and the horizontal width with [`.getComputedTextLength()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength).* The height according to the font metrics is the same for all characters in the `tspan`, so it is enough to return one [`.getExtentOfChar(0)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getExtentOfChar) - `0` refers to the first character within the sequence of addressable characters.

As chrwahl pointed out in his answer, the start position refers to the font-specific baseline and normally will not be identical to the top left corner of a bounding box.

*There is a subtle trick here: if the `letter-spacing` or `word-spacing` CSS properties were defined, the "length" returned would not only return the width from the start of the first character to the end of the last, but also would add (or subtract) a spacing value that is defined after the end of the string. In other words: despite its name, the method returns the relative horizontal start position of the *next* character after the string examined.

```js
var tsp = document.getElementById('tsp1');
var tspPos = tsp.getStartPositionOfChar(0);
console.log('start position', tspPos.x, tspPos.y);
console.log('horizontal advance', tsp.getComputedTextLength());
console.log('vertical extent', tsp.getExtentOfChar(0).height);
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">

    <text class="t1" id="t1" font-size="20" font-family="PT Mono" text-decoration="underline">
        <tspan class="tsp1" id="tsp1" x="10.23" y="135.05">Abc ef ghi</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is simply awesome. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

It is all about the [dominant-baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline). So, there is a differences between where the text is placed according to the dominant-baseline and the box that the text takes up. The value `text-before-edge` will place the text according to the upper left corner of the box.

```js
var tsp = document.getElementById('tsp1');
var tspBBox = tsp.getBBox();
var rect = document.getElementById('rect1');
var rectBBox = rect.getBBox();

console.log('tspBBox', tspBBox.x, tspBBox.y);
console.log('rectBBox', rectBBox.x, rectBBox.y);
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 100 400 200">
  <text class="t1" id="t1" font-size="20" font-family="PT Mono"
    text-decoration="underline" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">
    <tspan class="tsp1" id="tsp1" x="10.23" y="135.05">Abc ef ghi</tspan>
  </text>
  <rect class="rect1" id="rect1" x="9.23" y="112.73368530273439" height="31.546314697265625" width="1" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```